# Is it feasible to hide column in a grid in Power Bi Paginated report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have found a way to hide a column in the matrix visualisation in Power BI but not in Paginated report, hence question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Design view, you can hide a column by right clicking the column header and selecting **Column Visibility...**

[image: Right click header]

then select **Show**, **Hide**, or **based on an expression**

[image: display options]

To tie showing or hiding the column based on a drop down, create a parameter by right clicking **Parameters** in the **Report Data** pane and selecting **Add Parameter...**

[image: Add Parameter]

Here are my settings for the parameter:

- **General** tab:
- [image: general]
- **Available Values** tab:
- [image: Available Values]
- **Default Values** tab:
- [image: Default Values]

Once you have the parameter set, go back into the **Column Visibility** settings, select **based on an expression** and click the **fx** button:

[image: based on expression]

Then click **Parameters** and double click your parameter name to add the expression:

[image: add expression]

When you run the report, you'll see the drop down and the default setting:

[image: default setting]

You can then change the drop down and click **View Report** to see the hidden column:

[image: Show hidden column]